# How to merge a branch which has been forked from another into it ? (in order to get the latest commit from original branch)

Tags: git, merge, fork

I own a rock960 model c by 96boards and their kernel github repository (96rocks) is forked from rockchip-linux kernel one...

How do i do to merge 96rocks 'release-4.4-rock960' branch into rockchip-linux 'stable-4.4-rk3399-linux' ?

When i compare these two branches through github UI , it's telling me that they are not automatically mergeables...

Comment: 96rocks is a github user and i am talking about their kernel repository

Comment: Yup, I gave an answer on that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

So the goal is, they are behind the repo they are forked from, and you'd like your own copy to be up to date? Clone the https://github.com/96rocks/kernel repository to your own machine; it is now your `origin` remote. Now, on your own machine, add the https://github.com/rockchip-linux/kernel as another remote; name it `upstream` (that is conventional). Now you can fetch from `upstream` and merge into your local branch that comes from `origin`.

Comment: OK. I cloned https://github.com/96rocks/kernel and added https://github.com/rockchip-linux/kernel as a new remote and fetched it but when i want to merge it into my local branch that i am interested into, it's not working... I am interested into release-4.4-rock960 from origin and it is behind develop-4.4 from upstream : i tried 'git checkout -b rock960-tests origin/release-4.4-rock960' and then 'git merge upstream/develop-4.4' but it is failing...

Comment: That's not a failure. That's conflicts. Fine. You have to resolve them. You're the one who wanted to merge these things. Resolving conflicts is what you have to do in order to merge them. You _knew_ when you started that this was not going to be some sort of trivial fast-forward merge; that was in the premise of your question.

Comment: OK. i will tell you if i succeeded in it. Thanks for your help.